# Azure Active Directory for a small ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, azure, active-directory

What are the pros and cons of Azure Active Directory to manage the accounts of a simple website (at most 10 accounts, just for login to control panel), instead of SQL membership provider or the new bogus identity system in my own database. I never tried this service before but I like the fact that I don't need to take care of the database and credentials of my users, it's free and very secure I guess. Someone has tested it in production? any security advise? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the many upsides there's that it is free, highly available, enterprise-grade and basically management-free - all flows for entering and changing passwords and similar are already implemented for you. Also, it can be used for both web sites and web API - so that if tomorrow you want to add a mobile app for the same user population, we've got you covered.
About having tested it in production... yes, there are many many (MANY) apps using AAD in production today.
I guess that one possible downside for such a small use case is that all the defaults are set to a higher security level than you'd probably use in your scenario, translating in a bit more involvement from your users: passwords templates requiring special characters, mandatory password expiration, and so on. Of course to me it's a good thing, but I am biased :-) 
Another current limitation is that the user names must be of the form alias@yourADdomain, as of today you cannot use an arbitrary string. That's usually not a big deal, but calling it out in case you have preexisting user names you need to stick to.

HTH
V.